# Common ThreadPool Configuration for Camel and SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, threadpool

Is it possible configure a common thread pool for Spring Boot and Camel in my application?

Below is spring configured pool

```
@Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);        
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

Want to use the same pool for camel routes as well.

But unable to set to camelContext `ExecuteServiceManager`

```
camelContext.setExecutorServiceManager(??);// unable to set above pool here.
```

Comment: Can someone help me with above?